# how to extract from drop down menu using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: sports menu]

I want to scrape sports menu "text" as highlighted above.
https://ekusports.com/

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"}

url = "https://ekusports.com/"

reqs = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'html.parser')

website_text = soup.findAll(text = True)
```

Comment: You can't scrape that using BS. It's rendered by JS, so you'll need a browser.

Comment: @0stone0 that's not true.

Comment: It is, you're getting the raw json and processing that. Not really the same as OP's asking for IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the endpoint to get the menu data.

Here's how:

```py
import requests


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}

r = requests.get("https://ekusports.com/services/sportnames.ashx", headers=headers).json()
print("\n".join([s["sportInfo"]["sport_title"] for s in r["sports"]]))
```

Output:

```
Baseball
Beach Volleyball
Bratzke Center
Cheerleading
Colonel Club
Cross Country
Dance Team
Development
EKUSports Builds
Football
General
Marketing/Promotions
Men's Basketball
Men's Cross Country
Men's Golf
Men's Tennis
Men's Track and Field
Name/Image/Likeness (NIL)
Soccer
Softball
Spirit Groups
Tickets
Track & Field
Volleyball
Women's Basketball
Women's Cross Country
Women's Golf
Women's Tennis
Women's Track and Field
```

Comment: hi @baduker can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390939/how-to-get-the-proper-link-from-a-website-using-python-beautifulsoup

Answer (score -1):

If you are using beautiful soup, it might not be able to get a drop-down menu as they are rendered using JavaScript. You'd need a scraper such as

> Selenium

which automates browser and JavaScript renders, with browser window updates on each click, etc. Selenium is also very simple to work with.