# How to get the proper link from a website using python beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, gazpacho

When I try to scrape roster links, I get https://gwsports.com/roster.aspx?path=wpolo when I open it on chrome it changes to https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-water-polo/roster. I want to scrape it in proper format like the second one(https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-water-polo/roster).

```
pip install -U gazpacho

from gazpacho import get, Soup

url = 'https://gwsports.com'
html = get(url)
soup = Soup(html)
links = soup.find('a', {'href': "roster"}, partial=True)
s=[link.attrs['href'] for link in links]
print(s)
```

Comment: Don't spam with tags, you're not using `selenium` nor `beautifulsoup` here. Also, you're question is not clear. The link in the code is different to the ones you describe. Finally, what would your desired output be?

Comment: Sorry, I am new my mistake. My intention is to get roster links of every sport. https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-water-polo/roster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue with scraping, you're getting the exact URL that's on the page. Rather that URL redirects you to the final URL which is the one you need.
You can use `requests` library to get the final URL:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; ' \
    'Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'}

url = 'https://gwsports.com/roster.aspx?path=wpolo'

r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
if r.status_code == 200:
    print(r.url) # URL after redirections
else:
    print('Request failed')
```

Which makes your code like so:

```
from gazpacho import get, Soup
import requests

def get_final_url(url, root):
  # Note this function assumes url is relative and always prepends root
  # You may want to extend it to detect absolute URLs
  headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; ' \
    'Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0'}

  r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
  if r.status_code == 200:
    return r.url # URL after redirections
  else:
    raise requests.HTTPError

url = 'https://gwsports.com'
root = 'https://gwsports.com'
html = get(url)
soup = Soup(html)
links = soup.find('a', {'href': "roster"}, partial=True)
s = [get_final_url(root + link.attrs['href'], root) for link in links]
print(s)
```

Output

```
['https://gwsports.com/sports/baseball/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-basketball/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-golf/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-soccer/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-cross-country/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/mens-water-polo/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-basketball/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-gymnastics/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-lacrosse/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-rowing/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-soccer/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/softball/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-swimming-and-diving/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-tennis/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-cross-country/roster', 'https://gwsports.com/sports/womens-volleyball/roster']
```

Comment: OP is using `gazpacho` *not* `requests`. Also this does not produce any urls.

Comment: @baduker ```gazpacho``` doesn't offer URLs after redirection. Should I rewrite the solution with ```urllib``` which ```gazpacho``` uses? >"this does not produce any urls" it does for me, what output did you get?

Comment: Can you help me with this. @freshpasta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71405741/while-scraping-for-some-websites-i-get-object-is-not-iterable-error